# Which dialect of Markdown does Hackage use to render READMEs?

Tags: haskell, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, hackage

Hackage has been able to display Markdown READMEs [for a while](https://www.well-typed.com/blog/2015/05/recent-hackage-improvements/).

But as one can see for example on [the Hackage page for `hpack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hpack-0.16.0#readme), Hackage doesn't seem to support the same table syntax as GitHub.

#### Markdown:

```
#### <a name="flags"></a>Flags

| Hpack | Cabal | Default | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `description` | `description` | | Optional |
| `manual` | `manual` | | Required (unlike Cabal) |
| `default` | `default` | | Required (unlike Cabal) |
```

#### Rendered on GitHub:

[image]

#### Rendered on Hackage:

[image]

So, I'm wondering:

- Which Markdown dialect does Hackage support?
- Is there a syntax for tables in that dialect?
- Is there a syntax for tables in the subset of Markdown that is supported by both GitHub and Hackage?

Comment: I am not voting to close: this doesn't appear to be a question asking for a library/tool recommendation at all, but rather a question about what tool Hackage uses. It seems perfectly on-topic to me, and well-phrased as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick [search through the source](https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=markdown) of Hackage shows that is uses [`cheapskate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cheapskate-0.1.0.5) (by John MacFarlane, the author of Pandoc). Looking at the [`Cheapskate.Types`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cheapskate-0.1.0.5/docs/Cheapskate-Types.html) you can see everything that is supported - and tables are not part of that.

Furthermore, it appears that Hackage [has the raw HTML option for rendering set to `False`](https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Markdown.allowRawHtml), thereby quashing any hope one may have had of putting in a simple HTML table (which I think should also work in GitHub).

I think the best alternative (supported by both Hackage and GitHub) is just to put your table in a code block. That way, it is at least monospace font (so columns can align). That means you enter something like

````
```
| Header1 | Header2 | Header2 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Cell1   | Cell2   | Cell3   |
+---------+---------+---------+
```
````

And it will render as

```
| Header1 | Header2 | Header2 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Cell1   | Cell2   | Cell3   |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the well-researched answer! I have submitted [a request](https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server/issues/565) to support a larger subset of GitHub-flavored Markdown!

Comment: @sjakobi I reckon your best chance is probably if Hackage decides to enable inline HTML. Moving away from `cheapskate` would probably be a bad idea (it is fast and forgiving), and I think `cheapskate` won't be interested in adding non-standard features.

Comment: You may be right. I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/jgm/cheapskate/issues/18) for `cheapskate` anyway.